# How to use the property of normal subgroup to show the following

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$, i.e., $g^{-1}Ng = N$ for all $g\in G$.

How to show that for all $g,\, h\in G$, we have

$\{xy: x\in Ng \text{ and } y\in Nh\} = Ngh.$

---

My effort is that I know

$$Ngh = \{ngh : n \in N\}.$$

Now $$xy = (n_1g)(n_2h) = n_1gh h^{-1}n_2h,$$ since $h^{-1}n_2h\in N,$ we let $h^{-1}n_2h = n_3$, so we get

$$xy = (n_1g)(n_2h) = n_1gh h^{-1}n_2h = n_1ghn_3,$$ then I still have no idea how to show that $n_1ghn_3$ is in $Ngh$

Comment: You can use that left and right cosets of $N$ with respect to $g\in G$ are equal.

Comment: Instead of using $g^{-1}Ng=N$, use $Ng=gN$. So $(n_1g)(n_2h) = n_1(gn_2)h = n_1(n_3g)h$.